# Android: testing IAB in-app purchase with license test response addresses

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I am trying to test IAB in-app purchase. I would like to know if entering gmail address of a test account in the "license test response" field (developer console/settings) is enough to be able to test the in-app purchase workflow for a managed product (app is in alpha channel and product is active) or it is mandatory to create a test group/community for the alpha channel. Then I wonder if creating the that test group/community would be enough for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough if you publish the application to the alpha channel, you **won't need** to setup a Google+ **Community** for this. Actually the Community-Stuff is only there for entering the Test-Group and through this being able to download the APK. Since you're the developer you already have the signed APK.

Just as an info: You need to use a signed apk with your certificate in order to be able to test the In-App purchases. An APK signed with a debug-certificate (e.g. when you hit the Play-Button in your IDE) won't work. Furthermore the version number must match with those in the alpha-channel.